# Is it possible to execute multiple python project unit test suites with one driver given my repo structure?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

**Background**

I have a repo for a new set of projects written in python. I have multi level folders set up to distinguish each tool when a developer checks out the repo. Something like the following:

```
repo
    project1
        __init__.py
        project1
            __init__.py
            code
        tests
            __init__.py
            test_something
    project2
        __init__.py
        project2
            __init__.py
            code
        tests
            __init__.py
            test_something
```

**Problem**
A developer gave me a `pytest` regression test script that executes all project unit tests in a given directory, however given my project structure it is unable to run. The driver cannot import any of the modules so the regression script fails immediately on Module errors.

I tried updating the project level **init** files with

```
import os, sys

for relativePath in ["/", "/..", "/../*, "/../tests"]:
    fileLoc = os.path.dirname(os.path,realpath(os.path.abspath(__file__))) + relativePath
    if( True == os.path.exists(fileLoc) and ( fileLoc not in sys.path) ):
        sys.path.append(fileLoc)
```

but I don't believe that is going to be useful given the two folders per project.

**Question**

Is it possible to execute all unit tests at the "repo" level?

Would restructuring the repo be a better choice?